# How to get substring of unicode characters from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The Unicode characters are stored in mysql database in this format

```
&#1740;&#1729;&#1575;&#1722; &#1578;&#1608;
```

There is no only unicode characters in my database by also html and english characters mixed up.

The Problem is I want to get a part of the string from database field `'post_body'`
I have used the following sql query

```
"SELECT SUBSTRING(post_body,1,120) as pst_body from mytable";
```

This string gives me back 120 characters accurately. But the Problem is if there are unicode symbols in the database then `&#1740; is equal to 1 unicode character`, so my requirement does not fulfill in this way. 
Is there any function that can give me back my specified number of characters regardless of is it unicode character or english character, mean if there is unicode data it should count `&#1740;` as one character .

Comment: Try `SET NAMES 'utf8'` before that query.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, there is any option in mysql, you can fetch data from mysql then take the action in PHP.

```
function getSubstring($string, $number){

    $keywords = preg_split("/([&])+/", htmlentities($string));
    $finalArray = array();
    unset($keywords[0]);

    for($index = 1;$index <= $number;$index++){
        $finalArray[] = $keywords[$index];
    }
    return str_replace('amp;', '&', implode('', $finalArray));
}

 //$string = &#1740;&#1729;&#1575;&#1722; &#1578;&#1608;
 //$number = 10;// number of character to be fetch
 echo getSubstring($string,10);
```